# SurfaceView error

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, paint

```
   @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){  
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                update();
                canvas.drawCircle(XC, YC, radius, paint);
                }
```

render method in SurfaceView
Minimize the program for the first time - everything is fine when unfold.
When refolding is an error

```
04-29 22:57:16.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4813): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23150

04-29 22:57:16.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4813): java.lang.NullPointerException

04-29 22:57:16.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4813): at com.example.blindballtest.GameField.onDraw(GameField.java:10 1)

04-29 22:57:16.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4813): at com.example.blindballtest.ThreadGame.run(ThreadGame.java:42)
```

Tell me, please, what's wrong and how to fix it?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
  @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){  
            this.oDraw(canvas);

            }
private void oDraw(Canvas canvas){
Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            update();
            canvas.drawCircle(XC, YC, radius, paint);
}
```

Comment: swears on  super.oDraw(canvas);